# Problems extending twisted.web's static.File class

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I'm trying to add transcoding support to some server I'm writing, I need to get in between the request being received and being carried out.

Currently I've got:

```
class TransCodingFile(static.File):
def render(self,request):
    static.File.render(self,request)
```

but when I try to request a file I get a:

"Failure: exceptions.RuntimeError: Producer was not unregistered for xxx.mp4" error

The new class works as static.File if I remove the render() method.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was stupid.

```
class TransCodingFile(static.File):
    def render(self,request):
        return static.File.render(self,request)
```

works fine. I wish the error message was more helpful.